# Adjusting tikzpicture baseline to be flush

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, baseline

I have two minipages one which encloses a tikz picture.  I'd like these to have the same baseline.  i.e. I would like the minipages to be flush at the top.

By default this doesn't happen:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 1]

I can set the tikz picture's baseline to `(current bounding box.north)`:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 2]

But that's about half a line of text below the intended baseline.  Curiously when I adjust the size of `TEXT` to be larger using `\huge`, the baseline of the tikz picture seems to move down to maintain this property.  This happens even when the tikz picture occurs first:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE 3]

How can I get the baseline set so that the two boxes are flush at the top?

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the tikz picture baseline altogether.  Enclose the picture in a minipage and use some do-nothing text to establish a baseline for the minipages:

```tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\vspace{0mm}%For alignment
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.05\textwidth}
\vspace{0mm}%For alignment
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

This has the drawback that the width of the fbox is now determined by the minipage (here it's `0.05\textwidth`) not the tikzpicture.  However the vertical alignment is perfect without the need to fiddle with magic numbers or anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt failed because the height of `TEXT` is not the height of `\strutbox`.

There are two reliable solutions.  First, use `\hrule` to move the first baseline to the top of the minipage.  Second, use `\raisebox` to move the baselines to the top of the `\fbox`es.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,tikz}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\hrule height0pt
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  \draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
  \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}\hfill\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline

\raisebox{-\height}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT}
\end{minipage}}}
\raisebox{-\height}{\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0)node{$\square$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}\hfill\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Context of your question is unknown. Solution apparently depends on size of your `tikzpicture`. In particular case, as is provided in question, I guess that this should work:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.75ex]
\node {$\square$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

An example with bigger `tikzpicture`

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1.6ex] current bounding box.north)}]
\node[draw, minimum size=12mm] {$\blacksquare$ $\blacksquare$};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth}
\textbf{TEXT} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

However, the first example remain me on some list with square symbol for item. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\square$]
\item   \textbf{TEXT} \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]